# A proving question based on DeMoivre's theorem.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Prove that$$\frac{1+\sin(1/8)π+i \cos(1/8)π}{1+\sin(1/8)π–i \cos(1/8)π} =\; –1$$ I tried to solve this by converting it into $e^{ik\alpha}$ but could not rationalize it please help me out.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961689/prove-that-frac1-sin-theta-i-cos-theta1-sin-theta-i-cos-theta-sin-the

Comment: The  correct spelling is  deMoivre ..... or de Moivre.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1+\sin(\pi/8)+i\cos(\pi/8)}{1+\sin(\pi/8)-i\cos(\pi/8)}
&=\frac{1+ie^{-i\pi/8}}{1-ie^{i\pi/8}}\frac{ie^{-i\pi/8}}{ie^{-i\pi/8}}\\
&=\frac{1+ie^{-i\pi/8}}{1+ie^{-i\pi/8}}ie^{-i\pi/8}\\[7pt]
&=ie^{-i\pi/8}\\[12pt]
&=e^{i3\pi/8}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The given equality is not true.

Upon cross multiplication of $$\frac{1+\sin(1/8)π+i \cos(1/8)π}{1+\sin(1/8)π–i \cos(1/8)π} =\; –1$$

We get $$1+\sin(1/8)π+i \cos(1/8)π= -1-\sin(1/8)π+i \cos(1/8)π$$

Which is equivalent to $$1+\sin(1/8)π= -1-\sin(1/8)π$$ or $$\sin(1/8)π=-1$$ which is obviously false.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps...just expand 1 in terms of sin and cos

[image]

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Are you sure that  $e^{i\pi /8} =-1$?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Actually this question is wrong sir ; RHS will have sinpi/8 + i cospi/8

Comment: If the question is wrong then how did you get that answer?